# Programmatically setting textbox value but returning run-time error 438

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to set the value of a text box based on the value I select in a combo box and a pre-existing value in another text box. Both the controls are in a continuous subform within a form.  When I select a value in the combo box, I get the following:

```
Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method
```

My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Combo1_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection

     Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ssql = "(SELECT TABLE1.DESCRIPTION As d1 " & _
"FROM TABLE1 " & _
"INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON " & _
"(TABLE1.CATEGORY = TABLE2.CATEGORY) " & _
"AND (TABLE1.LEVEL = TABLE2.LEVEL) " & _
"WHERE " & _
"(((TABLE1.LEVEL)= " & [Forms]![MainForm].[Subform].[Combo1] & ") " & _
"AND ((TABLE2.CATEGORY)= '" & [Forms]![MainForm].[Subform].[CATEGORY] & "'));)"

    rs.Open ssql, con

    Do Until rs.EOF = True

       [Forms]![MainForm].[Subform].TextBox1.SetFocus

       [Forms]![MainForm].[Subform].TextBox1.Text = rs.Fields!d1

       rs.MoveNext

    Loop

End Sub
```

I've searched quite a bit online, and can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try referring instead to [Forms]![MainForm].[Subform].Form.TextBox1

[Subform] refers to the object on Mainform. You need to qualify it with Form to refer to objects within it.

Comment: I changed all instances of controls to use that additional 'Form' qualifier. Now I get the following error:  "Run-time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)': No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: And when I run the debugger, it highlights the following line of code: rs.Open ssql, con

Comment: Okay, that was happening because I had introduced a typo into a data element name in my SQL. Now, I get no error messages at all. But Combo1 doesn't actually change to whatever value I pick, and the code doesn't change the value in TextBox1, either. I pick a value in the combobox, nothing happens. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: Alright, I've almost got this working. One key was to save the record OnDirty for Combo1, then execute the code to update TextBox1 AfterUpdate. Everything works, except that I get the following error message every time I change a value in Combo1: `Run-time error '2115': The macro or function set to the BeforeUpdate or ValidationRule property for this field is preventing Database from saving the data in the field.`  The problem I was having to open this question is resolved, so I'm going to close this, and post this new error as a new question. Thanks for your help.